# i may have crossed some blackwires on a switch

Tags: wiring

I am replacing switch in the basement and switch has 3 black wires. That switch is now turning the kitchen light on. What happened. I believe I know what I did but not sure which way to put the wires back in to rectify it. There is a wall switch in my basement stair case that controls one of the areas in my basement. I went to put a new switch on the basement wall. This is when I found out there are 3 12/2 wires coming in to the switch box. The 3 black wires are connected to the switch and the 3 white wires are tied off with a wire nut. 2 of the black wires are connected to the switch and the other black wire is connected at one of the 2 ends of the switch where there is a screw to tighten. Is it possible that I may have switched one of the black wires?

Comment: We're going to need much more info to help you -- perhaps some photos of the inside of the junction box?

Comment: More likely than not, power for the kitchen light passed through that junction box and you mixed up wires.  You're gonna have to trace 'em out (which you have to do anyway to provide enough info for folks here to provide suggestions).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. there is no junction box and I did not touch any of the kitchen lights. Possible that there is a GFI on the other side of the wall between the kitchen and basement staircase. Is it possible that I could have miswired the swith with the black wires?

Comment: I know it sounds funny. The switch is a standard single pole type. 2 of the black wires were a push in type and the other black wire went to the brass screw. Could I have screwed up when I put the 3 black wires on. Other than that the white were twisted together with a wire nut and the ground wires went to the grounding screw.

Comment: Yeah, that kind of thing is only funny in cartoons. ThreePhaseEel is on it, as usual. There are just too many ways to make things worse, without more information. Did you remove 3 wires from the switch? Did it work before you replaced it ? I would expect a screw at each end of the switch, 2, 3 and 4 screws are all 'normal' numbers for switches in a house. We know that 1 of the wires is connected to your kitchen light. Does the kitchen light switch work normally, with the new switch in either position ?

Comment: Ok, 2 push in places, and 2 screws. The switch is the only one that should turn on and off the light (single pole, as you said). We really are moving forward. We know that when the new switch is in the 'on' position, the kitchen lights come on. That tells us that the side with the single wire connected to the kitchen lights.

Comment: The switch did work before I ran the wires to it. and you can either stab the wires into the switch or use the screws to connect the wires. There is a light switch on the other side of the wall from the basement wall. I somehow grabbed the power from this wire when I rewired it. The kitchen light now only works from the new switch but not from the kitchen light switch and the light in the basement does not turn off from the new switch. There is where the 2 different levels of the house and 2 different walls all come together.

Comment: You are correct. I'll switch the wires back in the morning.

Comment: You are correct. When the switch is up the kitchen come on but the basement lights won't turn off.

Answer (score 1):

You likely switched wires.  It sounds like the thee wire pairs consist of:

- Power feed
- Line to kitchen light switch
- Line to basement light.

From your description switch was being used to bridge the power feed to the kitchen light using push in connection and the screw connection.  (This may not be to code.)

It appears the power feed and basement light are on the same side of the switch.  Try moving the wire on the screw to the other screw.  If this fixes things, the power feed is on the screw.